# PHP Add 4 hours to date

Tags: php

I'm trying to add four hours to a date but the resultant time is incorrect

```
$date = $dates[0] < $dates[1] ? $dates[1] : $dates[0];
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours', $date));
echo $date;
echo "<br/>". $new_date;
```

The result i'm getting is

> 2015-09-17 09:36:18
>
> 1969-12-31 20:33:35

The first date is correct but the second isn't, it should be 4 hours ahead of the first

Comment: The first date is not a UNIX date. Right?

Comment: the first date comes from a datetime field in mysql

Comment: `var_dump(strtotime('+4 hours', $date))` will show a boolean false,which means `$date` is **NOT** unix time stamp. boolean false is integer 0, as far as `date()` is concerned, which'd come out as Jan 1/1970

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$date = $dates[0] < $dates[1] ? $dates[1] : $dates[0];
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours', strtotime($date)));
echo $date;
echo "<br/>". $new_date;
```

You were passing `$date` AS the second argument of strtotime, and it's not a UNIX timestamp (as you said). So with strtotime again, you should convert it in a UNIX timestamp, and then pass it to strtotime.

---

Comment: Could you please emphasis on your improvement?

Answer (score 2):

Add timestamps to a timestamp, not to a date string.

```
echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours', strtotime("2015-09-17  09:36:18")));
                                                ^
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/435084)**

That is the right syntax.  You can simplify it however with

```
echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2015-09-17 09:36:18 +4 hours'));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/435086)**

Answer (score 2):

You're using strtotime incorrectly. Its second argument MUSt be a unix timestamp:

```
php > var_dump(strtotime('+4 hours', 12345));
int(26745)
php > var_dump(strtotime('+4 hours', '2015-09-17 09:36:18'));
PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in php shell code on line 1
int(16415)
```

Your call should be

```
php >  var_dump(date('r', strtotime('2015-09-17 09:36:18 + 4 hours')));
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
string(31) "Thu, 17 Sep 2015 13:36:18 -0500"
php >
```

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers are correct.

Not seeing what you have in your $dates array makes it a bit tricky to give exact answer :) but in the following example i assumed you have a well formatted string date, in which case you need to convert it back to the timestamp using same method (strtotime) before adding what you like into it .

```
$date = (new DateTime('now'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+4 hours', strtotime($date)));

echo $date . PHP_EOL . $new_date;
```

In other word, if your `$date` array contains UNIX time stamp then your original code should work

```
$date = (new DateTime('now'))->getTimestamp();
$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+4 hours', $date));
```